# Set delay and terminate ACTION_CALL intent

Tags: android, android-intent, handler

I have an app which dials the appropriate number when user click on a card. so i want to add a delay and cancel feature where an alert dialog or progress bar is shown to user for 5 seconds with a cancel button to terminate the delay within the time frame .

I tried using handlers and runnable but whenever a call is initiated, the cancel button just dismiss the dialog window but doesn't stop the Delay.

Is there any other approach to this?

Thanks.

Below is my **onClick** method

```
   @Override
public void onClick(final View view) {

    if (getAdapterPosition() == 0) {
        //Do nothing here - Header Position
    } else if (getAdapterPosition() == 1) {

        dialog = new ProgressDialog(view.getContext());
        dialog.setCancelable(true);
        //dialog.setIcon(resId);
        dialog.setTitle("Calling Fire Service" );
        dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        dialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        dialog.setIndeterminateDrawable(view.getContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.police_animation));
        dialog.show();
        dialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                        callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:192"));
                        view.getContext().startActivity(callIntent);
                    }

                }, 5000);
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });


    } else if (getAdapterPosition() == 2) {
        Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
        callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:193"));
        view.getContext().startActivity(callIntent);
    } else if (getAdapterPosition() == 3) {
        Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
        callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:191"));
        view.getContext().startActivity(callIntent);
    } else if (getAdapterPosition() == 4) {
        Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
        callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:18555"));
        view.getContext().startActivity(callIntent);
    } else if (getAdapterPosition() == 5) {
        view.getContext().startActivity(new Intent(view.getContext(), SafetyActivity.class));
    } else if (getAdapterPosition() == 6) {
        view.getContext().startActivity(new Intent(view.getContext(), FirstAidActivity.class));
    } else {
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: keep calling code in handler for delay. In case user presses cancel button, cancel handler and fire call Intent.

Comment: @NightFury Thanks, i have done that before but i forgot to add the Latest code changes. Kindly review the code as the problem still persist.